# How to set custom predefined macros for gcc via Linux environment to avoid passing them all the time

Tags: linux, gcc

I have several projects in which I use many custom macros. For example,

```
//prog.c

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DBG_LEVEL_1
#define P(d) printf("%s:%d\n", #d, d);
#else
#define P(...)
#endif

#ifdef INLINE
#define INL static inline
#else
#define INL
#endif

INL void func_Sqr(int a)
{
  printf("sqr(a):%d\n", a*a);
}

int main()
{
  int a = 3;
  P(a);
  func_Sqr(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile this in several ways,

```
gcc prog.c
gcc -DINLINE prog.c
gcc -DDBG_LEVEL_1 prog.c
gcc -DDBG_LEVEL_1 -DINLINE-DINLINE prog.c
```

Is there way to set these macros as enabled as default via environment variable?

We can solve this by creating a makefile where these macros are set. **But I want to know if there any Linux environment related solution**

Comment: You can set environment variable for each of those macros and invoke that variable with `gcc` and your source file. Should be trivial to do it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to set these macros as enabled as default via environment variable?

Generally, no there is not. Gcc arguments are not affected by environment variables (except maybe `DEPENDENCIES_OUTPUT`..).

I advise to write a small wrapper function around the command, for example a bash function:

```
wgcc() {
   gcc "${GCCARGS[@]}" "$@"
}
```

and then doing:

```
GCCARGS+=(-DA=1 -DB=2)
wgcc something.c
```

is trivial to do, easy to understand and maintain and communicate with other team members, easy to implement and share. Suprising haisenbugs will be easy to track - `wgcc` is unique name different then `gcc`. Still you could overwrite the original command with `gcc() { command gcc "${GCCARGS[@]}" "$@"; }` or by creating a `/usr/local/bin/gcc` file, making it a bit more confusing.

But! You can and I woult strongly advise not to do that, because it will be confusing to others and hard to maintain. You can use [COMPILER_PATH](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) environment variable to overwrite compiler tools and provide custom options. In steps:

- Create a temporary directory
- In that directory link all the subprograms of gcc to it's normal prefix, except the tools the behavior you want to modify, like `cc1`.
- Then create `cc1` as a script with that will call the original `cc1` but will use some environment variable to pass extra arguments.
- Then export the path as COMPILER_PATH so gcc will pick it up.

On my archlinux with gcc10.0.1 I did:

```
mkdir /tmp/temp
cd /tmp/temp
for i in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/{cc1plus,collect2,lto-wrapper,lto1}; do ln -vs "$i"; done
printf "%s\n" '#!/bin/sh' '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.1.0/cc1 $GCCARGS "$@"' > cc1
chmod +x cc1
export COMPILER_PATH=/tmp/temp
```

After that you can:

```
export GCCARGS=-DA=1
gcc -xc - <<<'int main() { printf("A=%d\n", A); }'
./a.out
> A=1
```